# Converting absolute path to relative

Tags: javascript, jquery, relative-path, absolute-path

What is best way to convert absolute path to relative path by javascript or jquery ?

for example consider as below :

```
"http://localhost:2011/Content/Images/Product/Large/3.jpg"
```

to

```
 "/Content/Images/Product/Large/3.jpg"
```

Comment: that is not a relative path. To be relative it has to be relative to something. For example if the page is `http://localhost:2011/Content/Pages/Page.html` then the relative path is `../Images/Product/Large/3.jpg`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the trick that `<a>` elements contain location properties.

```
$("<a href='http://localhost:2011/Content/Images/Product/Large/3.jpg'>")
  .prop("pathname");
```

Comment: Excellent trick! Can you refer to any documentation explaining that 'pathname' prop? What are the other props we can rely on?

Comment: @abernier: [Here's a list.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement#Properties) It does state it's HTML5, though. I'm not aware of cross-browser support.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `window.location.pathname`

Comment: There is no a method provided naturaly by javascript or jquery ?

Comment: @AnyOne: It's 2-3 lines of code. No need for a library function: Take the length of the host part, make sure that the URL starts with the host part, create substring starting at host-part.length.